# I'm an artist. What is the rule to name an artwork in English? (When can I use articles "the/a/an" and when I no necessary to use it?) Thank you

Tags: articles, definite-article

I see the names of artworks on the link, sometimes I see articles, sometimes I see they do not use it.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/100_Great_Paintings

Comment: There is no 'rule'. 'A Tree in the Spring' and 'Dead Dog in River' are both possible.

Comment: The title of a work of art can be anything the creator wishes. It does not even have to have any meaning, and could be an invented word or words. I could call a poem, painting, or novel etc, 'Rqrxxz56' if I wanted.

Comment: Some works are even called "Untitled 1" for instance.